# What food is suggested for Yogi?

Tags: food, spirituality, yogi

For spiritual progress I want to know the role of food intake. Which type of food is suggested in scriptures for one who want to approach the path of Yoga? In other words, do Shastras recommend or instruct particular foods (to be taken) which helps one's spiritual journey be smooth?

Looking for answers from scriptures or from speech/sayings of personalities like Swami Vivekananda who believed to be perfect Yogi.

Comment: In decreasing order of ideality/strength of aspirant - 1. Nothing. 2. Air (vayu bhaksha). 3. Water (jal bhaksha). 4. milk (satvik, must be obtained following many rules). 5. fruits/vegetables (many must be avoided, especially onion/garlic/mushroom). 6. grains - obtained using aja-gara vritthi (whatever falls on your plate), kapota vritthi (only obtaining what's needed for 1 day, no saving for tomorrow), uncha vritthi (only grains fallen on ground after harvest). 7. of the 6 tastes - sweet,salt,sour,spicy,bitter, thuvarpu (can't find good english word) - only sweet.

Comment: @ram post an answer instead of comment.

Comment: I would like to add to this Q instead of a new one. Can one consume broiler eggs which are sterile? Because there is no "Himsa" (killing) involved. Answers below say about giving up fish, meat; but no mention about sterile eggs. Any pointers? Thanks.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto , you said that sterile egg is like unborn baby. But as you know it well, sterile means, incapable of producing. So where is the question of baby? Further, "killing unborn baby" is quite entertaining. How can we kill something which is not born?

Comment: @Vineet, ahimsa is an important goal, it is not the highest goal. even eating onion/garlic is ahimsa (no animal harmed) yet it is regarded as worse than meat for yogi because of its sensory-inciteness. we are not discussing vegetarianism, but satvik-ism. and by definition, satvik food is ahimsa (not other way around). egg is not satvik even though it's not himsa. Still, it's only avoiding direct himsa, not indirect himsa, because egg-industry and chicken-industry are literally like pregnant mother and unborn child. Feeding mother helps feed child, and Buying eggs helps kill chicken.

Comment: @ram , Thanks. You have got a valid point. I need to introspect on this point.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Hatha Yoga Pradipika](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/hyp/hyp03.htm) (1.61 to 1.70) gives the list of foods that are fit for the Yogi as well as those foods which a Yogi must avoid.

Recommended foods are rice, wheat, milk etc.

> Varjayeddurjanaprāntam vahnistrīpathisevanam
>  Prātahsnānopavāsādi
>   kāyakleśavidhim tathā ||
>
> Wheat, rice, barley, shâstik (a kind of rice), good corns, milk, ghee,
>   sugar, butter, sugarcandy, honey, dried ginger, Parwal (a vegetable)
>   the five vegetables, moong, pure water; these are very beneficial to
>   those who practise Yoga.

> Ghodhūmaśāliyavashāshtikaśobhanānnam
>  Kshīrājyakhandanavanītasi
>   hāmadhūni
>  Śunthīpatolakaphalādikapañchaśākam
>   Mudghādidivyamudakam cha yamīndrapathyam ||
>
> A Yogî should eat tonics (things giving strength), well sweetened,
>   greasy (made with ghee), milk, butter, etc., which may increase humors
>   of the body, according to his desire

Now, the list of food which a Yogi must avoid while practising Yoga. This list includes foods like meat, liqour, sour, bitter foods etc.

> Katvāmlatīkshnalavanoshnaharītaśāka
>   Sauvīratailatilasarshapamadyamatsyān
>   Ājādimāmsadadhitakrakulatthakola
>   Pinyākahingghulaśunādyamapathyamāhuh||
>
> Bitter, sour, saltish, hot, green vegetables, fermented, oily, mixed
>   with til seed, rape seed, intoxicating liquors, fish, meat, curds,
>   chhaasa pulses, plums, oilcake, asafœtida (hînga), garlic, onion,
>   etc., should not be eaten.

A Yogi must also always eat food which is first offered to Lord Shiva.

> Susnighdhamadhurāhāraśchaturthāmśavivarjitah
>  Bhujyate
>   śivasamprītyai mitāhārah sa uchyate||
>
> Abstemious feeding is that in which ¾ of hunger is satisfied with
>   food, well cooked with ghee and sweets, and eaten with the offering of
>   it to Śiva.

So, these are some rules about eating to be followed by a Yogi from Hatha Yoga Pradipika.

Comment: Can you also include what recommended in Tantra ?

Comment: I never read anything like that in Tantras so far.. @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: No problem; I know what is recommended in Tantra. Just don't have any reference; So thought you might have.

Comment: You can't eat green vegetables? Aren't almost all vegetables green?

Comment: There are many vegetables which are not green,, for e.g. root vegetables (potato, carrot, beetroot, etc).. Yes while practicing Yoga a Yogi shd not eat those veggies. That is for him to follow not for any other persons. @Ikshvaku

Answer (score 13):

[**Yogatattva Upanishad**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yogatattva-upanishad-of-krishna-yajurveda/d/doc217055.html) (3rd paragraph ) gives a small glimpse of it with generally healthy vegetarian food is enough for a Yogi

> The proficient in Yoga should abandon the food detrimental to the practice of Yoga.
>   He should give up salt, mustard; things sour, hot, pungent, or bitter vegetables; asafoetida,
>   etc., worship of fire, women, walking, bathing at sunrise, emaciation of the body by fasts, etc.
>   During the early stages of practice, food of milk and ghee is ordained; also food consisting of
>   wheat, green pulse and red rice are said to favour the progress

Comment: Good answer. My upvote. Can you pl give any url or scan for my study purpose? and also cite exact verse from "Yogatattva Upanishad"?

Answer (score 4):

The Upanishadic advice is to eat food that keeps your body healthy. Treat food as a type of medicine.

> After saying thrice, ‘I have renounced, I have renounced, I have
>   renounced’, he shall take up the bamboo staff and don the loin-cloth,
>   uttering the mantra: ‘Let all beings be devoid of fear. Everything
>   originates from me. You are my friend and [you] protect me. You are
>   the strength, my friend. You are the vajra of Indra that killed Vrtra.
>   Be pleasant to me and remove all my sins.’ **He shall pertake of food as
>   if it were medicine. He shall eat as if taking medicine. He shall eat
>   as and when food is obtained.** ‘Oh [disciples], protect brahmacarya,
>   non-injury, non-possession and truth with care.’ 1
>
> 1 The outer and inner aspects of these qualities are: brahmacarya
>   (outer) = celibacy, (inner)=the dwelling of the mind on Brahman;
>   ahimsa=not injuring others, non-injury of oneself;
>   aparigraha=non-possession of anything other than what is needed for
>   bare subsistence, non-concern with all but Brahman;
>   satya=truthfulness, realization of the true nature of the Self.

*Arunyupanishad translated by Prof A A Ramanathan*

Chandogya Upanishad says that some spiritual aspirant takes a vow to not eat fish and meat for a year or to permanently stop eating non-veg food. The exact shloka is:

> He who thus knows this Yajnayajniya Saman, woven in the limbs of the
>   body, is endowed with all the limbs, and is not crippled in any limb;
>   he reaches the full length of life, lives gloriously, becomes great
>   with offspring and cattle and great also with fame. His holy vow is
>   that he should not eat fish and meat for a year, or rather, he should
>   not eat fish and meat at all.

*Chandogya Upanishad 2.19.2*

Swami Vivekananda has also discussed the question of food for Bhaktas.

> The question of food has always been one of the most vital with the
>   Bhaktas. Apart from the extravagance into which some of the Bhakti
>   sects have run, there is a great truth underlying this question of
>   food. We must remember that, according to the Sankhya philosophy, the
>   Sattva, Rajas, and Tamas, which in the state of homogeneous
>   equilibrium form the Prakriti, and in the heterogeneous disturbed
>   condition form the universe — are both the substance and the quality
>   of Prakriti. As such they are the materials out of which every human
>   form has been manufactured, and the predominance of the Sattva
>   material is what is absolutely necessary for spiritual development.
>   The materials which we receive through our food into our
>   body-structure go a great way to determine our mental constitution;
>   therefore the food we eat has to be particularly taken care of.
>   However, in this matter, as in others, the fanaticism into which the
>   disciples invariably fall is not to be laid at the door of the
>   masters.
>
> And this discrimination of food is, after all, of secondary
>   importance. The very same passage quoted above is explained by
>   Shankara in his Bhâshya on the Upanishads in a different way by giving
>   an entirely different meaning to the word Âhâra, translated generally
>   as food. According to him, "That which is gathered in is Ahara. The
>   knowledge of the sensations, such as sound etc., is gathered in for
>   the enjoyment of the enjoyer (self); the purification of the knowledge
>   which gathers in the perception of the senses is the purifying of the
>   food (Ahara). The word 'purification-of-food' means the acquiring of
>   the knowledge of sensations untouched by the defects of attachment,
>   aversion, and delusion; such is the meaning. Therefore such knowledge
>   or Ahara being purified, the Sattva material of the possessor it — the
>   internal organ — will become purified, and the Sattva being purified,
>   an unbroken memory of the Infinite One, who has been known in His real
>   nature from scriptures, will result."
>
> These two explanations are
>   apparently conflicting, yet both are true and necessary. The
>   manipulating and controlling of what may be called the finer body, viz
>   the mood, are no doubt higher functions than the controlling of the
>   grosser body of flesh. But the control of the grosser is absolutely
>   necessary to enable one to arrive at the control of the finer. The
>   beginner, therefore, must pay particular attention to all such
>   dietetic rules as have come down from the line of his accredited
>   teachers; but the extravagant, meaningless fanaticism, which has
>   driven religion entirely to the kitchen, as may be noticed in the case
>   of many of our sects, without any hope of the noble truth of that
>   religion ever coming out to the sunlight of spirituality, is a
>   peculiar sort of pure and simple materialism. It is neither Jnâna, nor
>   Bhakti, nor Karma; it is a special kind of lunacy, and those who pin
>   their souls to it are more likely to go to lunatic asylums than to
>   Brahmaloka. So it stands to reason that discrimination in the choice
>   of food is necessary for the attainment of this higher state of mental
>   composition which cannot be easily obtained otherwise.

*The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, Volume 3, Bhakti Yoga, The Method and the Means*

**A note of caution**

Food suggested in any Hatha Yoga book is not accepted by all Yogis. This is because some Yogis think that Hatha yoga is bad for spirituality.

It is bad according to Sri Ramakrishna.

> A DEVOTEE: "Sir, what is hathayoga like?"
>
> MASTER: "A man practising hathayoga dwells a great deal on his body.
>   He washes his intestines by means of a bamboo tube through his anus.
>   He draws ghee and milk through his sexual organ. He learns how to
>   manipulate his tongue by performing exercises. He sits in a fixed
>   posture and now and then levitates. All these are actions of prana. A
>   magician was performing his feats when his tongue turned up and clove
>   to the roof of his mouth. Immediately his body became motionless.
>   People thought he was dead. He was buried and remained many years in
>   the grave. After a long time the grave somehow broke open. Suddenly
>   the man regained consciousness of the world and cried out, 'Come
>   delusion! Come confusion!1 (All laugh.) All these are actions of
>   prana.
>
> "**The Vedantists do not accept hathayoga.** There is also rajayoga.
>   Rajayoga describes how to achieve union with God through the mind — by
>   means of discrimination and bhakti. **This yoga is good. Hathayoga is
>   not good.** The life of a man in the Kaliyuga is dependent on food."

*The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, With the devotees at Dakshineswar (II), December 9, 1883*

> MANILAL: "And what about hathayoga?"
>
> MASTER: "The hathayogis identify themselves with their bodies. They
>   practise internal washing and similar disciplines, and devote
>   themselves only to the care of the body. Their ideal is to increase
>   longevity. They serve the body day and night. **That is not good**.

*The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, The master in various moods, October 2, 1884*

Comment: Do we have Sanskrit Mantra too for bold texts ?

Comment: I have renounced (3 times) means this is about some Sannyasa ritual.. it probably has nothing to do with Yoga.. it is an instruction for a Sannyasi

Comment: No, the English translation does not give anything in Sanskrit.

Comment: No one is asking whether Vedantins accept Hatha Yoga or not.. Who cares? When people fall ill they go to learn Yoga and not to Vedantins.. Empty doctrines don't bring solace to anyone.. Apart from that Hatha and Raja Yogas are complementary to each other and not enemies like you're trying to prove by quoting one line. Hatha Yoga Pradipika itself says this- @PradipGangopadhyay

Comment: Hatham vinā rājayogho rājayogam vinā hathah
Na sidhyati tato yughmamānishpatteh samabhyaset||  
No success in Râja Yoga without Hatha Yoga, and no
success in Hatha Yoga without Râja Yoga. One should,
therefore, practise both of these well, till complete
success is gained

Answer (score 3):

As per Ramana Maharshi

http://bhagwan-ramana-maharshi.blogspot.com/2008/12/ramana-maharshi-on-vegetarianism-eating.html

http://spiritualblossoms.blogspot.com/2010/08/sri-ramana-maharshi-diet.html

> Question : What about diet?
> Ramana Maharshi : Food affects the mind.
> For the practice of any kind of yoga, vegetarianism is absolutely
> necessary since it makes the mind more sattvic [pure and harmonious].
>
> Question : Could one receive spiritual illumination while eating flesh
> foods?
> Ramana Maharshi : Yes, but abandon them gradually and accustom
> yourself to sattvic foods. However, once you have attained
> illumination it will make less difference what you eat, as, on a great
> fire, it is immaterial what fuel is added.
>
> Question : We Europeans are accustomed to a particular diet and a
> change of diet affects the health and weakens the mind. Is it not
> necessary to keep up one's physical health?
> Ramana Maharshi : Quite
> necessary. The weaker the body the stronger the mind grows.
>
> Question : In the absence of our usual diet our health suffers and the
> mind loses strength.
> Ramana Maharshi : What do you mean by strength of
> mind?
>
> Question : The power to eliminate worldly attachment.
> Ramana Maharshi
> : The quality of food influences the mind. The mind feeds on the food
> consumed.
>
> Question : Really! Then how can Europeans adjust themselves to sattvic
> food only?
> Ramana Maharshi : Habit is only adjustment to the
> environment. It is the mind that matters. The fact is that the mind
> has been trained to think certain foods tasty and good. The food
> material is to be had both in vegetarian and non-vegetarian diet
> equally well. But the mind desires such food as it is accustomed to
> and considers tasty.
>
> Question : Are there restrictions for the realized man with regard to
> food?
> Ramana Maharshi : No. He is steady and not influenced by the
> food he takes.
>
> Question: Is it not killing life to prepare meat diet?
> Ramana Maharshi
> : Ahimsa [non-violence] stands foremost in the code of discipline for
> the yogis.
>
> Question : Even plants have life.
> Ramana Maharshi : So too the slabs
> you sit on!
>
> Question : May we gradually get ourselves accustomed to vegetarian
> food?
> Ramana Maharshi : Yes. That is the way.
>
> Question : Is it harmless to continue smoking?
> Ramana Maharshi : No,
> for tobacco is a poison. It is better to do without it. It is good
> that you have given up smoking. Men are enslaved by tobacco and cannot
> give it up. But tobacco only gives a temporary stimulation to which
> there must be a reaction with craving for more. It is also not good
> for meditation practice.
>
> Question : Do you recommend that meat and alcoholic drinks be given
> up?
> Ramana Maharshi : It is advisable to give them up because this
> abstention is a useful aid for beginners. The difficulty in
> surrendering them does not arise because they are really necessary,
> but merely because we have become inured by custom and habit to them.
>
> Question : Generally speaking, what are the rules of conduct which an
> aspirant should follow?
> Ramana Maharshi : Moderation in food,
> moderation in sleep and moderation in speech.

Comment: Beautiful! Bhagwan(Ramana Maharshi) also suggested same as recommended in Tantra.

Answer (score -1):

Sanatana Dharma aka Hinduism has 4 sects of people depending on their duty

Brahmin (one whose life is of knowledge)
   ex:- Teacher, priest, doctor, scholar, architect, judge..

Kshatriya (one whose life is of a warrior)
   ex:- soldier, king, cop, fireman etc.,

Vaishya (one whose life is of trade)
   ex:- shop owner, trader, businessman

Shudra (one whose life is of labor)
   ex:- construction worker, engineer, driver etc.,

Brahmin and Vaishya's profession requires their mental health, alertness and well being to higher than any of their other well being (physical, social etc.,). So the foods suggested are satvik --> vegetarian, dairy, honey and so on. There are a lot of aphrodisiac vegetarian food and they are to be avoided too. It is common knowledge that those who are sexually more active always involve in those thought are less capable of being rational in dealings with those to whom they are sexually attracted. If you are a straight heterosexual business man or a priest with your diet involving a lot of aphrodisiacs then your chances of getting compromised with those of opposite sex are more. vegetarian food which doesn't affect your mood, rationality, alertness etc are recommended. Coffee is vegetarian, mushrooms are vegetarian and so are many drugs. So anything that doesn't affect the natural state and well being of your body and mind is fine.

Shudra and Kshatriya's duties require that they prioritize their physical wellbeing. That is why tamasic food (meat, aphrodasiacs, alcohol etc.,) are not forbidden or ill advised for them.

If you are following the satvic (hatha, pranayama etc.,) way of yoga then eat satvic food.
If you are following the tamasic way of yoga (kundalini, tantric) then you can even go for the tamasic food too but strictly under a guru's guidance.

Comment: Welcome to hinduism! Answers here must be backed with authentic reference to scriptures! Its compulsory!

Comment: @AkshayKumarS https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/conduct doesn't say anything about citation of scriptures being mandatory.

Comment: You should visit on how to answer questions. The code of conduct is with respect to how we should behave with fellow users! @TheDestroyer

Comment: please post a link to that. @AkshayKumarS

Comment: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions

Comment: i studied at a monastry when i was young and most of my information is from a GURU who is nomore alive. I cannot quote scriptures but this is my understanding. I guess readers may choose wisely based on the one with most citations.

Comment: We respect your Guru and your experience with him. Having said that, there must be references which can be cross-checked. There is no way to cross check personal experience like in this case.