# What food habits are recommended in hinduism for good health?

Tags: food

It is mentioned in hinduism that some caste people are prohibited from eating the non-vegetarian food, so how these people will get necessary nutrients to live the normal life?

Anywhere does food habits mentioned for one to follow in our religion to live healthy life?

I mean I am talking about sources of nutritions for vegetarians

Comment: Related: [What food is suggested for Yogi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29703/277)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are Tamasic, Rajasic and Sattvic foods?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2659/what-are-tamasic-rajasic-and-sattvic-foods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manu talks about food in the fifth chapter of his laws.

> 5. Garlic, leeks and onions, mushrooms and (all plants), springing from impure (substances), are unfit to be eaten by twice-born men.
> 6. One should carefully avoid red exudations from trees and (juices) flowing from incisions, the Selu (fruit), and the thickened milk of a
>      cow (which she gives after calving).
> 7. Rice boiled with sesamum, wheat mixed with butter, milk and sugar, milk-rice and flour-cakes which are not prepared for a sacrifice, meat
>      which has not been sprinkled with water while sacred texts were
>      recited, food offered to the gods and sacrificial viands,
> 8. The milk of a cow (or other female animal) within ten days after her calving, that of camels, of one-hoofed animals, of sheep, of a cow
>      in heat, or of one that has no calf with her,
> 9. (The milk) of all wild animals excepting buffalo-cows, that of women, and all (substances turned) sour must be avoided.
> 10. Among (things turned) sour, sour milk, and all (food) prepared of it may be eaten, likewise what is extracted from pure flowers, roots,
>       and fruit.
> 11. Let him avoid all carnivorous birds and those living in villages, and one-hoofed animals which are not specially permitted (to be
>       eaten), and the Tittibha (Parra Jacana),
> 12. The sparrow, the Plava, the Hamsa, the Brahmani duck, the village-cock, the Sarasa crane, the Raggudala, the woodpecker, the
>       parrot, and the starling,
> 13. Those which feed striking with their beaks, web-footed birds, the Koyashti, those which scratch with their toes, those which dive and
>       live on fish, meat from a slaughter-house and dried meat,
> 14. The Baka and the Balaka crane, the raven, the Khangaritaka, (animals) that eat fish, village-pigs, and all kinds of fishes.
> 15. He who eats the flesh of any (animal) is called the eater of the flesh of that (particular creature), he who eats fish is an eater of
>       every (kind of) flesh; let him therefore avoid fish.
> 16. (But the fish called) Pathina and (that called) Rohita may be eaten, if used for offerings to the gods or to the manes; (one may
>       eat) likewise Ragivas, Simhatundas, and Sasalkas on all (occasions).
> 17. Let him not eat solitary or unknown beasts and birds, though they may fall under (the categories of) eatable (creatures), nor any
>       five-toed (animals).
> 18. The porcupine, the hedgehog, the iguana, the rhinoceros, the tortoise, and the hare they declare to be eatable; likewise those
>       (domestic animals) that have teeth in one jaw only, excepting camels.
> 19. A twice-born man who knowingly eats mushrooms, a village-pig, garlic, a village-cock, onions, or leeks, will become an outcast.
> 20. He who unwittingly partakes of (any of) these six, shall perform a Samtapana (Krikkhra) or the lunar penance (Kandrayana) of ascetics; in
>       case (he who has eaten) any other (kind of forbidden food) he shall
>       fast for one day (and a night ).
> 21. Once a year a Brahmana must perform a Krikkhra penance, in order to atone for unintentionally eating (forbidden food) but for
>       intentionally (eating forbidden food he must perform the penances
>       prescribed) specially.
> 22. Beasts and birds recommended (for consumption) may be slain by Brahmanas for sacrifices, and in order to feed those whom they are
>       bound to maintain; for Agastya did this of old.
> 23. For in ancient (times) the sacrificial cakes were (made of the flesh) of eatable beasts and birds at the sacrifices offered by
>       Brahmanas and Kshatriyas.
> 24. All lawful hard or soft food may be eaten, though stale, (after having been) mixed with fatty (substances), and so may the remains of
>       sacrificial viands.
> 25. But all preparations of barley and wheat, as well as preparations of milk, may be eaten by twice-born men without being mixed with fatty
>       (substances), though they may have stood for a long time.
> 26. Thus has the food, allowed and forbidden to twice-born men, been fully described; I will now propound the rules for eating and avoiding
>       meat.
> 27. One may eat meat when it has been sprinkled with water, while Mantras were recited, when Brahmanas desire (one's doing it), when one
>       is engaged (in the performance of a rite) according to the law, and
>       when one's life is in danger.

There is more. [The Laws of Manu V](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu05.htm) You may read for yourself.

> It is mentioned in hinduism that some caste people are prohibited from
>   eating the non-vegetarian food, so how these people will get necessary
>   nutrients to live the normal life?

There is a big misconception that vegetarians are deficient in many nutrients. They are only deficient in Vitamin B12. Some websites and "internet hospitals" that claim vegetarians lack certain nutrients are selling half truths.

E.g., creatine deficiency, a common argument against vegetarians, is false. There is no such thing as creatine deficiency. A normal liver always produces the creatine one needs, if the liver is in working condition. It is true that meat eaters have more creatine, but there are no proven health benefits of having slightly more creatine in your body, either. I advise you not to rely on the Internet or a book for information on this. It is best to speak to a real doctor.