# Is there any technique how to overcome laziness in the morning and evening time?

Tags: spirituality

Whenever I wake up in the morning and thereafter when I try to read Bhagavad Gita, I feel very sleepy and lazy, and I’m not able to read Gita in the morning.

Even during the day, after lunch I feel very lazy and sleepy.

My daily routine goes like this and I’m not able to practise spirituality.

My question is that, is there any technique to overcome laziness in the morning and evening time?

Comment: It happens because of vikara present in form like cough or acidity. Do 7 chakra of Nadishodham Pranayama before reading.

Comment: i don't know  what is 7 chakra of Nadishodham @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: food and exercise.....

Comment: 7 chakra as in 7 times and here is a link on how to do nadi shodham pranayama : https://youtu.be/817fiBUDChg

Comment: @hanugm yeah food and exercise also play big role. I agree. You may be interested in this question: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29703/647

Comment: You have to train your willpower. You do not need Hinduism to do this. There are lots of youtubevideos about this watch them and try them out.

Comment: Satvik aahar. Just one day, try this : instead of having your usual lunch, have fruits - bananas, grapes, orange juice. I can guarantee 99% you will not feel sleepy that afternoon. If you try this experiment, and it works, then you can have normal lunch daily, but night-time dinner meal replace with fruits, and morning you'll feel much less sluggish

Comment: @Wikash_, of course you don't NEED hinduism. but hinduism can help. and those who want to avail that help can do so. And the answer given by hinduism is Satvik Aahaar.

Comment: thanks u @ram i will try this

Comment: Put some very hot chilis underneath your tongue when you feel tired and lazy. You will be surprised how awake you will become.